# Javascript addEventListener don't work if it's the second request in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, svg, internet-explorer-11, addeventlistener

I have to add two events to the same svg element, it works if I use firefox but it doesn't work if I use Internet Explorer 11 (last version) and it must work for IE11.

This is the code.

```
var aggEvenList = document.getElementById('test');

aggEvenList.addEventListener('mouseover', function (ev) {
ev.preventDefault();
/*do something */  
}, false);


aggEvenList.addEventListener('mouseleave', function (ev) {
ev.preventDefault();
/* do something */
}, false);
```

I tried to change mouseleave to mouseout or everything event but it never add and no error is returned on Console.

Thanks

Comment: It works http://jsfiddle.net/5snsz0u0/ Please provide a code snippet that doesn't work.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2964862 - might be worth a read.